# Combining two complex join queries to one

Tags: mysql, sql

First query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `records` a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT map, MIN(time) as time 
            FROM `records` GROUP BY map) as b ON a.time=b.time ORDER BY a.map
```

Second query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM `players` 
      WHERE cheat=0) c JOIN `records` a ON a.authid = c.authid
```

The first query finds the row for each unique `map` with the lowest `time` value.

The second query finds all rows in the `records` table that are *not* completed by a player in the `players` table with the `cheat` flag set to `1`.

My attempt to combine these two queries to find the lowest non-cheater time for each unique map is as follows:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `records` a 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE cheat=0) c ON a.authid=c.authid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT map, MIN(time) as time 
FROM `records` GROUP BY map) as b ON a.time=b.time ORDER BY a.map
```

It's quite obvious what's happening but I don't know how to correct it: instead of retrieving the lowest `time` without an enabled `cheat` flag it says that the lowest `time` is *not* a legit time and ignores the record for that `map`.

Any ideas on how I could properly combine these two queries?

Edit:

---

`records` structure:

```
map [varchar(32)] | authid [varchar(35)] | name [varchar(32)] | time [decimal(13,6)] | date [datetime] | weapon [varchar(32)]
```

`players` structure:

```
id [int(8)] | authid [varchar(20)] | name [varchar(32)] | rank [float] | perc [float] | points [float] | uwrs [float]
```

Comment: That second query doesnt need a subselect.  Just join the tables together with the conditions.

Comment: @tenub . . . Can you describe what you want the overall query to do?

Comment: "My attempt to combine these two queries to find the lowest non-cheater time for each unique map is as follows:" - do you need a better description? I can edit the question to show the structure of the two different tables if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your join in the first query is missing criteria and should be

```
ON a.time=b.time
AND a.Map=b.map
```

Although that is not the issue here, the issue is that you are selecting the first record for each map, then only keeping those completed by a non-cheat. You need to get the first record for each map competed by a non-cheat. It is a subtle difference and you just need to move your join to the players table into the subquery:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    records AS a
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  r.Map, MIN(r.time) AS Time
            FROM    records AS r
                    INNER JOIN players AS p
                        ON p.authid = r.authid
            WHERE   p.Cheat = 0
            GROUP BY r.map
        ) AS MinR
            ON MinR.map = a.map
            AND MinR.time = a.time
ORDER BY a.map;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will get you the desired result:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `records` a 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT map, MIN(time) as time
     FROM `records` r
     INNER JOIN `players` p
     ON a.authid = c.authid
     WHERE p.cheat = 0
     GROUP BY map) as b 
ON a.map = b.map AND a.time=b.time 
ORDER BY a.map;
```

First, the minimum times are obtained for only non-cheating players. Then the records are obtained for these times.

Also, I added `a.map = b.map` in the `JOIN` to ensure that the same maps are joined (in case there is more than one map with the same record time).